# How to merge 2 yaml files while keeping track of each value coming from which parent yaml in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have to merge 2 yaml files. The structure of both yaml files is almost same. While merging i have to add comments after each leaf element in the merged yaml that it came from which parent yaml.

I have successfully merged both yaml files, but couldn't find a solution on how to add comments in the merged yaml that it came from which file.

I merged them by reading them as maps in groovy with readyaml and then recursively merging both maps and then converting the result yaml back to yaml

Eg : 
a.yaml

```
id: a_yaml
some_key:
    key: value_1
```

b.yaml

```
id: b_yaml
some_key:
    key: value_2
```

Now b.yaml has more priority, so merged yaml

```
id: b_yaml      #This came from b_yaml
some_key:
    key: value_2      #This came from b_yaml
```

Now i was able to merge them successfully, but don't know how to add comments in the merged.yaml

Comment: I think you should provide a runnable piece of code and two simple input file ( maybe as gist)

Comment: Comments, according to the YAML spec, are a representation detail and *must not be used to convey content information*. Therefore, you cannot produce comments when serializing content (e.g. your merged map). You need to modify the YAML structure on the token level and I don't know of any YAML implementations that allow you to do that when writing to a file.

Comment: Ihmo, the simplest way to add new key-value with some suffix or prefix. Like `Key.SRC: came from a.yaml`

Comment: or you could write yaml by yourself. re-implement your algorithm to write the result directly into file.

Comment: i have added an example , please check if it is more understodable now

Comment: For now i have only merged both the yaml files , by converting them into a map , then recuversily creating a new map , and then converting the map back again to yaml, don't know how to add comment